# dependency injection with MEF in MVC3 seems abnormally slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, mef, performance

I have an MVC3  web application where controllers use services to perform certain tasks.
I use to instantiate the needed services in each action separately,like so for example:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ICustomService customService = new CustomService();
        var list = customService.ReturnSomething();
        .....
        return View(list)
    }
```

This was working fine. Then I decided to use MEF for dependecy injection in order to follow better design principles. So now I'm doing something like this:

```
   public class MyController : Controller
   {
    [Import]
    private ICustomService _customService;

    public MyController()
    {
        MEFManager.Compose(this);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      var list = _customService.ReturnSomething();
      return View(list);
    }
```

Where Composition is done by MEFManage.Compose(this) which is the following function:

```
    public static void Compose(object o)
    {
        var container = new CompositionContainer(
                                                new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(
                                                                       AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin"))
                                                                    );
        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        batch.AddPart(o);
        container.Compose(batch);
    }
```

This actually WORKS but it is  6 to 7 times slower than when I wasn't using MEF. 
Does anyone know why it is so slow? I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spinning up a `CompositionContainer` is not a resource intensive task, **but**, creating a `DirectoryCatalog` is, it has to scan all available assemblies to identify parts and analyse the composition elements for exports. You could improve this a number of ways:

1. You could have a singular `DirectoryCatalog` (or preferably a `ComposablePartCatalog`) that all your containers use when constructing, this means that the catalog creation is only done once.
2. You could avoid container creation in your constructor entirely and implement either an `IControllerFactory` to spin up your controller instances, or an `IDependencyResolver` to handle dependency resolution using MVC3's built in service location mechanism. There are many examples on the web if you search for MEF + MVC.

Comment: I chose the first solution you suggested and create a singular DirectoryCatalog in Application_Start. Its working fast again. Thank you. Ps: I had already read your articles on 'fidelitydesign.net' but failed to understand how they could have helped me for this problem.

Comment: @Martin - Those examples use implementations I discussed in Item #2 (above) - which is not the same approach you've taken for your project, probably why they didn't help you.

Comment: That being said, you're current class design for your constructor does hide its dependencies, and the class itself composes itself. While this does work, a better design would be to pass your `ICustomService` as an argument to the constructor, as this allows the API to express its dependency requirements. This would lead you to using Item #2 (above).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because each controller instance is rebuilding a CompositionContainer, which looks like it does some disk access.

Can you move the CompositionContainer initialisation into Application_Start?

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but it doesn't make it any faster. As @Matthew Abbott said in his answer, creating a CompositionContainer is not an intensive task.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really use MEF but I think your solution scans every assembly in the bin folder to search for Import/Export attributes and compose the application.

I don't think it is the right way to use MEF, the controller should not call any MEF related method.

It seems something similar if you would configure a DI container for each request.

This article seems good: [Using MEF 2 with ASP.NET MVC 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/11/11/using-mef-2-with-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to our article. We've been through a few iterations since it was published (a whole new composition engine!) so the Composition Provider currently is being distributed as a demo - Microsoft.Composition.Demos.Web.Mvc on http://mef.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets - rather than via NuGet. Some more info here: http://mef.codeplex.com/discussions/361444. Cheers!